# What to do if I get a HTTPInternalServerError in Ruby Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, exception, response, mechanize

I always get an HTTPInternalServerError (code 500) exception when navigating to a perticular website. However the website works great in every browser I tried (opera, chrome, firefox). My user agent string is set to 'Linux Firefox'. What can I do to make the website work with Ruby Mechanize gem?

Comment: Is the 500 error being returned by the server you're visiting, or by the computer that's running your script?

Comment: I get this error message: 500 => Net::HTTPInternalServerError for http://XXXXXXX.XXX/XXXXX.php -- unhandled response

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Can you write sample code.